# Multicolor progress bar using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a multicolor progress bar please help me to code. when progress less than 50 it will show red when progress is >50 and <90 it will show green and from 90 to 100 it show blue, how to do it??

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Show your code first or google it. Ex:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar6&stacked=h

Comment: You need to at least try it and present code sample you have worked on.

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/progress/#multiple-bars

Answer (score 1):

You need to create one div for the progressbar and then you just add divs inside the progressbar div.
`

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="fifty">
        <p>50%</p>
    </div>
    <div class="twentyfive">
        <p>25%</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ten">
        <p>10%</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

The CSS could be something like this:
`

```
    .bar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #b3b3b3;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fifty {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        float: left;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    }

    .twentyfive {
        width: 25%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
        float: left;
    }

    .ten {
        width: 10%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
        float: left;
    }
```

`

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got an idea how to do it,

Answer (score 0):

I created a multicolor progress bar.
Check it on my codepen here: https://codepen.io/onlintool24/pen/dyVJrww

Just need to change the var progressval value and you can see the multicolor progress bar.

```js
var progressval = 50;
var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('progressab')[0];
elm.style.width = progressval+"%";

elm.innerText = "You're "+progressval+"% There!";

if(progressval>90 && progressval<=100 ){   elm.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';                                 
}else if(progressval>50 && progressval<90 ){ elm.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}else if(progressval<=50){ elm.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```css
.progressa {
    border-radius: 50px !important;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 36px;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    line-height: 36px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
}
.progressab {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.15) 75%,transparent 75%,transparent);
    -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width .25s ease,height .25s ease,font-size .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: width .25s ease,height .25s ease,font-size .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: width .25s ease,height .25s ease,font-size .25s ease;
    -o-transition: width .25s ease,height .25s ease,font-size .25s ease;
    transition: width .25s ease,height .25s ease,font-size .25s ease;
    width: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif !important;
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite reverse;
}

@keyframes progress-bar-stripes{
0% {
    background-position: 40px 0;
}
100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="progressa">
<div class="progressab" style="    background-color: rgb(178, 222, 75);"></div>
</div>
```